# Security implications of a missing SCSV, but with only TLS 1.2 allowed

Tags: tls, webserver, web-service, tls-downgrade

Similar to this [security stackexchange question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112531/is-tls-fallback-scsv-useless-if-only-tls-1-0-1-1-1-2-is-supported), I was wondering if there's any downside, considering the services/servers security, if **only** TLS 1.2 allowed, but [TLS Fallback Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV) for Preventing Protocol Downgrade Attacks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7507) is **not** enabled.

Theoretically, I don't see any effect of the missing SCSV, as there's only TLS 1.2 available anyways, but I'm not 100% sure.

What effect does the absence of SCSV have, if only TLS 1.2 is allowed in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by "not enabled" on the server? Does that mean that the server will silently ignore it if it ever sees it? -- It's the client who is responsibly for setting this *"I've just just done a manual last resort fallback because you obviously can't handle a graceful fallback"* SCSV-flag. And the server is then required to either say *"Wait a minute! I can totally do a graceful fallback! Someone is messing with the connection! Quitting now!"* or say nothing because it really is that old and doesn't know SCSV yet.

Comment: "Not enabled", as in, "Only TLS 1.2 is enabled.". On NGINX this would look like `ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;`. Could you clarify your comment? I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: But can you actually explicitly disable SCSV? (The handling algorithm I described above.)

Answer (score 1):

Since the SCSV is merely a method to prevent downgrading and your server does not support any other protocols to downgrade to, I do not see any downside to that.

Correct me if I am wrong, but the SCSV would be for nothing with TLS 1.2 allowed only anyways.